# In Barbarona's "The Right to Kill", who kills the lieutenant and why?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-right-to-kill

At the end of [The Right to Kill](http://2017.tiff-jp.net/en/lineup/works.php?id=44) (Tu Pug Imatuy, 2017), the lieutenant gets shot by one of his own soldiers, but I did not have time to see who did it:

- The sergeant?
- The soldier who killed the indigenous man?
- One of the others?

And with what motivation?

- Hate for the young superior?
- Revenge?
- Will to save the indigenous woman?
- Slowly grown disgust for war?
- Realization that he can not survive as rebels are coming?

It will probably sound obvious to people familiar with the story, but it is not for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im arbi.
The Leautenant was shot by the sergeant, as he thought he was looking at a blurred image of Obunay, the woman protagonist.